# PHP creating an array of objects

Tags: php

Hi for what i understood it is possible to create an array of objects in PHP. When i try it something weird happens. This is the code

```
function createData($sheet, $rowsNumber, $rowOffset){

        $tempData = array();
        $temp = new Column();

        $insert = new InsertData();

        for($i = 0; $i < $rowsNumber; $i++){

            $temp->colName = "nome";
            $temp->colValue = $sheet->getCell('C'.$rowOffset)->getValue(); //nome
            $tempData[0] = $temp;
            $temp->colName = "cognome";
            $temp->colValue = $sheet->getCell('B'.$rowOffset)->getValue(); //cognome 
            $tempData[1] = $temp;
            $temp->colName = "dataNascita";
            $temp->colValue = $sheet->getCell('D'.$rowOffset)->getValue(); //dataNascita
            $tempData[2] = $temp;
            //$data[2] = date($format = "Y-m-d", PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($data[2])); //converte in formato data il valore numerico ottenuto da getCell 
            //echo($tempData[2]);
            $temp->colName = "sesso";
            $temp->colValue = $sheet->getCell('BK'.$rowOffset)->getValue(); //sesso  
            $tempData[3] = $temp;
            $temp->colName = "altrePatologie";
            $temp->colValue = $sheet->getCell('CF'.$rowOffset)->getValue(); //altrePatologie
            $tempData[4] = $temp;
            $temp->colName = "codiceDbCook";
            $temp->colValue =  $sheet->getCell('A'.$rowOffset)->getValue(); //codiceDbCook
            $tempData[5] = $temp;

            $insert->insert($tempData, "paziente");
        }

    }
```

This is what is inside of $tempData:

- 0:Column
  colName:"codiceDbCook"
  colValue:312
- 1:Column
  colName:"codiceDbCook"
  colValue:312
- 2:Column
  colName:"codiceDbCook"
  colValue:312
- 3:Column
  colName:"codiceDbCook"
  colValue:312
- 4:Column
  colName:"codiceDbCook"
  colValue:312
- 5:Column
  colName:"codiceDbCook"
  colValue:312

It takes the last value that it reads and put it in all the array. Can someone explain if it is possible to create an array of objects and if so what is wrong with what i am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of `Column` for every new column:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $rowsNumber; $i++) {
    $temp = new Column();
    $temp->colName = "nome";
    $temp->colValue = $sheet->getCell('C'.$rowOffset)->getValue();
    $tempData[] = $temp;

    $temp = new Column();
    $temp->colName = "cognome";
    $temp->colValue = $sheet->getCell('B'.$rowOffset)->getValue(); //cognome
    $tempData[] = $temp;

    // and so on, and so forth ...
}
```

BTW, if you already know indexes of your $tempData array, you can do it in even shorter way:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $rowsNumber; $i++) {
    $tempData[0] = new Column();
    $tempData[0]->colName = "nome";
    $tempData[0]->colValue = $sheet->getCell('C'.$rowOffset)->getValue();

    $tempData[1] = new Column();
    $tempData[1]->colName = "cognome";
    $tempData[1]->colValue = $sheet->getCell('B'.$rowOffset)->getValue(); //cognome

    // and so on, and so forth ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Just for my curiosity, do you know why it works this way?

Comment: It works like this because when you do `$tempData[0] = $temp;` PHP doesn't copy the whole `Column` object to `$tempData[0]` variable, it's just store a reference to initial object. So next time you modify the object that stored in `$temp` variable (eg. `$temp->colName = "new name"`), you will modify `Column` object in both `$temp` variable and `$tempData[0]` variable.

Comment: You can look closer what's going on with objects when you pass them to functions/set them to another vars by using `var_dump` (it shows unique object identifier in the output): https://3v4l.org/cTYq2

Comment: You can read more about this behavior here:
[Object Cloning ](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)
[Copy-on-write and reference counting for vars](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.variables.intro.php)

Comment: Thank you! gonna check that!

Comment: Just a small suggestion, take a look at [How PHP manages variables](https://entwickler.de/webandphp/how-php-manages-variables-125644.html). It explains all the details pretty good. Hope you find this article useful.